# numpy: extract multiple subarrays of a position array in an efficient way

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a 2D coefficient array COEFF with size row x col and a position array POS with size n x 2.

The goal is to create a batched array BAT with size n x (2*l) x (2*l) where l is the half length of subarray.

It looks like this

```
BAT[i, :, :] = COEFF[POS[i, 1] - l:POS[i, 1] + l, POS[i, 0] - l:POS[i, 0] + l]
```

It is possible to generate BAT based on above sequential code. However, I'm wondering is there an efficient way to construct the BAT array in parallel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a perfectly satisfactory solution to mixing advanced indexing and slicing in that way. But the following may be acceptable (assuming that by "parallel" you mean "vectorised"):

```
import numpy as np

nrow, ncol = 7, 7
n, l = 3, 2

coeff = np.random.randint(0,10, (nrow,ncol))
pos = np.c_[np.random.randint(l, nrow-l+1, (n,)),np.random.randint(l, ncol-l+1, (n,))]

i = (pos[:, :1] + np.arange(-l, l))[:, :, None]
j = (pos[:, 1:] + np.arange(-l, l))[:, None, :]

print(coeff, '\n')
print(pos, '\n')
print(coeff[i, j])
```

Prints:

```
# [[7 6 7 6 3 9 9]
#  [3 6 8 3 4 8 6]
#  [3 7 4 7 4 6 8]
#  [0 7 2 3 7 0 4]
#  [8 5 2 0 0 1 7]
#  [4 6 1 9 4 5 4]
#  [1 6 8 3 4 5 0]] 

# [[2 2]
#  [3 2]
#  [2 4]] 

# [[[7 6 7 6]
#   [3 6 8 3]
#   [3 7 4 7]
#   [0 7 2 3]]

#  [[3 6 8 3]
#   [3 7 4 7]
#   [0 7 2 3]
#   [8 5 2 0]]

#  [[7 6 3 9]
#   [8 3 4 8]
#   [4 7 4 6]
#   [2 3 7 0]]]
```